# Download file in react, sent by express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

None of the other solutions I have read on SO have worked so far, so please bear with me.

I have a frontend in React, where the user sends a request for a file download, along with some variables, to the backend:

```
const data = text.value;

fetch("http://localhost:4000/dl", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data,
        file: filetypes.selected,
    }),
}).then((res) => {
    ...???...
});
```

the `data` variable is some JSON, like so: `{"arrowParens": "always"}`.

the `file` variable contains the filename to be downloaded: `.prettierrc`.

My backend is in NodeJs/express, and handles the request like so:

index.ts:

```
app.use("/dl", getFile);
```

getFile.ts:

```
import appRoot from "app-root-path";

const index = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { data, file } = req.body;

    // download file if folder exists
    if (fs.existsSync(`${appRoot}/tmp/${file}`)) {

        res.sendFile(
            ".prettierrc",
            {
                dotfiles: "allow",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "json",
                },
                root: path.join(__dirname, "../tmp"),
            }
        );
    }
};
```

I'm getting the correct response back from the server: `POST /dl 200 11.878 ms - 55` but the file isn't downloading, so I think I have to have some extra code. I've read another post where OP created an anchor tag, and set the `href` to the blob url, but this doesn't seem to work since the response doesn't show me a URL. I had to opt for the `POST` request since I have to send those file-determining variables. Not sure if method makes a difference here.

How do I get the browser to prompt the download of my `.prettierrc` file? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an anchor tag with href and trigger the click.
something like this

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/dl", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data,
        file: filetypes.selected,
    }),
}).then(resp => resp.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = id;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, the anchor tag variation doesn't seem to work. `const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` creates `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`

Comment: What response are you getting from the API call? did u check in postman if postman is able to download the file ?

Comment: Postman does show the corresponding JSON under `body`, I think that means it works with Postman. It also sends the key values of file and data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but when I set the content type to the same in my frontend app, the backend doesn't receive any data. Should postman have some type of different response if it receives a downloadable file?

Comment: Your question says, download file ... how come you are receiving JSON and not the encoded blob data in the postman response. Am i missing something.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. What should I be receiving? How do I send anything other than the JSON per the above code? You're asking the same question that I am asking

Comment: I see what you were asking. When I click on `Send and Download` I still have to enter the filename manually, but the content then is what I expect to see in the file.